# MySQL SELECT distinct with multiple similar rows

Tags: mysql

I am struggling to get the correct data returned, I have a table with the following data structure:

```
# order_id, name
'10434', 'docs_sent'
'10433', 'placed'
'10433', 'docs_sent'
'10433', 'agreement_received'
'10432', 'placed'
'10431', 'placed'
'10431', 'docs_sent'
'10430', 'placed'
'10430', 'docs_sent'
'10430', 'agreement_received'
'10429', 'placed'
'10429', 'docs_sent'
'10429', 'agreement_received'
'10428', 'placed'
'10428', 'docs_sent'
'10427', 'placed'
```

What I am trying to do is return a unique "order_id" where "name" does not include agreement_received. So to clarify I am looking for a list of order numbers "order_id" where the order number does not have any record with agreement_received". The issue is that each order has multiple entries and I cant seem to get it right. PLEASE HELP!

The output should be similar to:

```
# order_id
'10434'
'10432'
'10431'
'10428'
'10427'
```

Comment: You'll get more eyes if you add a "sql" tag to your "mysql" tag, too.

Comment: where is your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table name is `t`:

```
select distinct t1.order_id
from t as t1
where t1.order_id not in
   (select t2.order_id
    from t as t2
    where t2.name = 'agreement_received')
```

Output:

```
+----------+
| order_id |
+----------+
|    10434 |
|    10432 |
|    10431 |
|    10428 |
|    10427 |
+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to *group by* order_id and only keep those order_ids *having* no 'agreement_received' record.

```
select order_id
from mytable
group by order_id
having sum(name = 'agreement_received') = 0;
```

(This uses MySQL's special boolean treatment. False = 0, True = 1. In other dbms you would have to use `sum(case when name = 'agreement_received' then 1 else 0 end)`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct order_id
from orders
where name != 'agreement_received';
```

Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT order_id
FROM MyTable
WHERE name <> 'agreement_received'
GROUP BY order_id
HAVING COUNT(order_id) = 1
```